# Automated update of SharePoint List from .csv file

Tags: list, infopath, updatelistitems

Our company wishes to keep an updated SharePoint List of our current customers for use in a InfoPath form.

Our ERP system is capable of exporting this on a timer job to a certain location (i.e. a disk drive) in the form of a .csv file.

My question is in regards on how to set up our SharePoint list, to automatically update itslef from this .csv file.

We would want something like a daily or weekly update during non-business hours.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a PowerShell script and Windows Task Scheduler to automate the import. Should be easier than a timerjob and faster to implement.

I wrote a similar script here: http://sp2010adminpack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Import-DataIntoSharePoint

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to do some custom development to automate this and I would probably go the route of a [custom timer job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc406686.aspx). Custom timer jobs are scheduled jobs that execute custom code. So you could write a job that reads the CSV files and updates the SharePoint items accordingly using the SharePoint API.